# Connection reset during Robot Framework execution

Tags: java, selenium, robotframework

I am a newbie to Robot Framework . Currently investigating a weird scenario happening with Robot Framework .

### Brief description about the issue

i am trying to start a server from Firefox browser using Robot Framework but every time getting connection reset with timeout on log .
but same operation is working as expected manually.

i am wondering how do i figure out the issue.

### Sample code

```
TEST_GUI-Select_TEST_Server_Control  
${select-all-TEST-location}    TEST_GUI- 
Set_element_locator_by_attribute_and_pattern    class    selAllSmall
TEST_GUI-TEST-CTRL-WRAPPER-CLICK-BUTTON-SELECTALL    ${select-all-TEST- 
location}
Capture Page Screenshot
Click Button    Stop    dont_wait
Wait until Keyword succeeds    5m    10s    UTIL-EXECUTE-COMMAND-FOR- 
ALL-TEST    TEST_GUI-TEST-Check-Status    Not Running
TEST_GUI-Select_TEST_Server_Control
${select-all-TEST-location}    TEST_GUI- 
Set_element_locator_by_attribute_and_pattern    class    selAllSmall
TEST_GUI-TEST-CTRL-WRAPPER-CLICK-BUTTON-SELECTALL    ${select-all-TEST- 
location}
Capture Page Screenshot
Click Button    Start    dont_wait
Wait until Keyword succeeds    15m    10s    UTIL-EXECUTE-COMMAND-FOR- 
ALL-TEST    TEST_GUI-TEST-Check-Status    Running
```

Comment: would you please share the code, it would help to understand.

Comment: Can you also please share the log file you refer to?

Comment: Sorry for delay response. As i have moved out of this project don't have further information.